# Can unix domain sockets be used to send file descriptors between processes when used in connectionless mode?

Tags: ipc, unix-socket

Basically, I'm wondering whether I can mix [this](http://blog.varunajayasiri.com/passing-file-descriptors-between-processes-using-sendmsg-and-recvmsg) with [this](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/netguide/dusockT.datagram_code_samples.html).

Use case is that I'm designing a multi-process server in which the worker processes must be able to send file descriptors to another, specific (depends on the fd) worker process, and I don't want to keep O(n^2) unix domain sockets open to have them all connected to each other.

The alternative, of course, would be to have them open a connection as needed, send one message, then close the connection, every time they need to send an fd.

The platforms I care about are Linux, OSX, HP-UX, AIX, and Solaris.

Comment: You should be able to; but you need to be aware that datagrams are not guaranteed delivery so you stand the chance of losing the packet.

Comment: My understanding is that unix domain sockets were guaranteed delivery, regardless of type. Do you have a link to documentation saying otherwise?

Comment: You're right @Bwmat I forgot about that. I suppose the only difference then is that the DGRAM might be easier to manage in your case.

Answer (score 0):

> > Can unix domain sockets be used to send file descriptors between processes when used in connectionless mode?

Yes. From man page:

> UNIX domain sockets support passing file descriptors or process
>          credentials to other processes using ancillary data.

Reliability is not a concern. Datagram sockets are always reliable.  Again from man page:

> UNIX
>          domain datagram sockets are always reliable and don't reorder
>          datagrams

And with Unix domain sockets the only tangible (or that one should consider) difference b/w stream and datagram socket is one being connection oriented and one connection less. "Stream" and "Bound messages" are not of concern.

Man page also mentions about `SEQPACKET` socket type that allows preserving message boundaries in a connection oriented setup.

So, one could keep things simple and use datagram sockets.